# How to prevent propagation of input box event when changing values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I understand event propagation can be stopped by using `event.stopPropagation()` on a "click" event for instance. I don't understand if in my case it is possible to do something like this to prevent the propagation.

I have a default event bound to textboxes when there is an input in it:

```
$('#inputbox').on('input', function () {
      // something
        }
```

Elsewhere in the code, I want to programmatically add text in the textboxes, but I don't want to trigger the default event. I just want the textbox to have the new text, without triggering any event:

```
$('#inputbox').val(values);
```

The code above triggers the input event. How can I use the `stopPropagation()` function in such case (with the `.val()` function)? I want to avoid going in the `.on('input')` function without changing it.

Comment: $('#inputbox).on(''input",function(){})

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#inputbox').on('input', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();//for internet explorer
    event.preventDefault();//for chrome/firefox
});
```

Comment: I don't want to change the event definition. I just want in a particular case to avoid going in it.

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of case?

Comment: I want the textbox to trigger the default event all the time except when I tell him not to. I just don't know how to tell him not to without changing the event definition

Comment: use a `if` statement. Something like `if(true){e.stopPropogation();}`

Comment: @kaycee I think you are confused about what you are asking

Comment: If you look here: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ , you see that the propagation is stopped right at the 'click' event. It can have a `.on('click' function(){})` also elsewhere but it will never be reached because it is stopped right at the click. That's what I want but when I use `.val()` on the textbox to change the text. I don't want to reach the `.on('input', function(){})` defined elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128962/discussion-between-aniket-sahrawat-and-kaycee).